# Dynamically compiling LINQ queries to verify a dictionary value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, lambda

Let us suppose we need to query on a list of entities and we do not know the criteria which is pretty much dynamic and the entity has both dictionaries and simple fields inside Let this be the next entity - Address(I left only one property for simplicity).

```
public class Address
{
    #region Public members

    /// <summary>
    /// The extra datafield values
    /// </summary>
    public IDictionary<string, string> DataFieldValues { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Now if we query on a fixed field called **City** when I got the implementation:

```
   private static Expression<Func<Address, bool>> BuildLambdaForAQueryItem(string caption, string value)
        {
            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Address), caption);
            BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, caption),
                                                     Expression.Constant(value,
                                                                         typeof(Address).GetProperty(
                                                                             caption).PropertyType));
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<Address, bool>>(body, param);
        }
```

Now if I want to query on a **DataFieldValue** coolection I need to write a lambda similar too:

**x=>x.DataFieldValues.ContatinsKey(key) && DataFieldValues[key]==value**
What I get with the method below is almost [similar](http://screencast.com/t/ahHbcIAqK) but still it does not apply the filter correctly:

```
private static Expression<Func<Address, bool>> BuildLambdaForAnExtraField(PostedQueryItem queryItem)
{
    ParameterExpression dataFields = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Address), "x");
    var dictionaryExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(dataFields, "DataFieldValues");
    var keyExists = Expression.Call(dictionaryExpression, "ContainsKey", null, Expression.Constant(queryItem.Caption));

    Expression dictionaryAccessExpr = Expression.Property(dictionaryExpression, "Item",
                                                           Expression.Constant(queryItem.Caption));
    var valueCorresponds = Expression.Equal(dictionaryAccessExpr, Expression.Constant(queryItem.Value));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Address, bool>>(keyExists, dataFields).And(
      Expression.Lambda<Func<Address, bool>>(valueCorresponds, dataFields));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use  [`Expression.AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353520.aspx) (a short-circuiting AND) on the two predicate expressions in question to construct the body of the expression-tree.

```
var body = Expression.AndAlso(keyExists, valueCorresponds);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<Address, bool>>(body, dataFields);
```

**EDIT**: (If you want to stick with your existing technique)

My guess is that your `And` method is an extension-method from the [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) library. If so, note that this extension involves 'invoking' the right-hand side expression with the parameters of the first expression as part of producing the result. If this isn't acceptable to you (LINQ provider limitations, perhaps?), you can use the useful `Expand` extension that also comes with this library to 'inline' the invoked expression.

```
return Expression.Lambda<Func<Address, bool>>(keyExists, dataFields)
                 .And(Expression.Lambda<Func<Address, bool>>(valueCorresponds, dataFields))
                 .Expand();
```

But this is *massive* overkill in this case; my advice is to go with my first sample.

Comment: You are right, thank you. But I still don't understand why my previous implementation did not work out